# What is the relation between entropy and quantum information?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, black-holes, quantum-information, entropy, information

I know that there is an important connection between quantum information and entropy, but exactly is the relation between them?

Also, is there a connection between black hole lost information and entropy?

Comment: you can have a look at these notes by William Fedus on the relation between entropy and QI: http://acsweb.ucsd.edu/~wfedus/pdf/courses/210a_assignment.pdf. Btw, both your questions are quite broad, so I would at least try and ask them as separate questions, preferably adding more detail to each

Answer (score 1):

The entropy of a qubit is $S = -Tr \left(\rho \log_2 \rho\right) $ where $ \rho$ is the density matrix of the qubit, Look up the Von Neumann entropy. Roughly speaking, anything that increases information(however you end up defining information for your system) decreases entropy. Most times physicists use the entropy as a measure of information so that there is no difference between the two.

Classically, Shannon's source coding theorem says that N independent and identically distributed variables each with with entropy $H$ can be compressed into $NH $ bits.

As with regards to black hole information paradox although concepts from quantum information theory techniques are proving to be useful the ultimate paradox has to do with the conflict between unitarity of quantum mechanics and the equivalence principle of general relativity.